# VideoJS isn't displaying anything in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to get a video to work with videoJS and with the help of the videoJS guide I got it working on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8.

I've added the CDN tags to my head and created a videotag.

I'm using the following:

```
<video id="my_vid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="244px" height="196px"
  poster="img/poster.jpg">

  <source src="files/mymov.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <source src="files/mymov.webm" type='video/webm' />
  <source src="files/mymov.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

It seems like the Flash fallback isn't working in IE8, since it doesn't create a flash object when I look in my inspector (which it does at the homepage of videojs.com). The video tag just remains, and IE8 can't cope with that. The video on the homepage of videojs.com is shown properly in IE8.

What am I doing wrong?

Solved: It seems like I had to add data-setup="{}" as an attribute in the video tag. The only problem now is that the video won't play in Chrome.

Comment: The trick of adding data-setup="{}" just worked for me - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can force videJS to display flash. You can use rtmp streaming to use flash

```
vjs.options.techOrder = ["flash", "html5", "links"];


    $(document).ready(function() {



        setTimeout(function() {

        vjs("videoPlayer").ready(function() {

                var swfVideo = $("#videoPlayer_flash_api")[0];
                swfVideo.vjs_setProperty("RTMPConnection", "path");
                swfVideo.vjs_setProperty("RTMPStream", "videoName");
            });

        }, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: I believe that the adding of **vjs.options.flash.swf** is only necessary when you're not using the **CDN version**?

Comment: Sorry i havent seen you have used CDN Version

Comment: You are right. You dont have to use vjs.options.flash.swf in CDN version